# Return a new modified field object from a scala function that the input parameter is based on a trait

Tags: scala, scalaz

I'm trying to model a trait/class structure to a generic Data Access Layer using Slick, but to limit just on fundamental part I'll post a basic code that have the general idea of the problem.

Suppose I have a base trait that define the common attributes for a Entity.

```
trait Base {
  def id: Option[Long]
  def version: Long
}
```

Now I'll create the Entities based on that trait.

```
case class User(id: Option[Long], version: Long, name: String, age: Int) extends Base
```

And a function that will get the Base type to be generic. At that point I can create, update the objects on database without problem. My problem is when I want to return the original object with the generated id returned from database.

```
def insert[M <: Base](m: M): M = {
  //insert on database and get the new ID
  val newId = Some(10)
  // Now I want to return the object with the newId
  // As Base is a trait I don't have copy
  m
}

val user = User(None, 1, "Test", 34)
insert(user)
```

To illustrate I would like to get a new User with id = Some(10) as result for insert function.

I thought about use copy, but it will work if I declare the function with a Base case class instead a Trait, but isn't what I want initially.
I tried to use Lens, like scalaz Lens. But I'll need copy too.

I'm missing something? There is another way to do it without using Reflection?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use F-bound polymorphism to require a `withId` method on the trait that is required to return the expected type:

```
trait Base[Self <: Base[Self]] { self: Self =>
  def id: Option[Long]
  def version: Long
  def withId(id: Long): Self
}
```

You can then implement `withId` on any case class by calling its native `copy` method:

```
case class User(id: Option[Long], version: Long, name: String, age: Int) extends Base[User] {
  def withId(id: Long) = this.copy(id = Some(id))
}
```

Then you could define your `insert` method as:

```
def insert[M <: Base[M]](m: M): M = {
  m.withId(10)
}
```

And the rest should work as expected.

The real problem is that `copy` is a special compiler-generated method, and you cannot require its existence on a trait.  This use of F-bound polymorphism allows you to work around this limitation with limited boilerplate.

Another approach is to just add another trait, say `HasWithId` that guarantees the `withId` method, and extend/require that wherever needed:

```
trait Base {
  def id: Option[Long]
  def version: Long
} 

trait HasWithId[M] {
  def withId(id: Long): M
}

case class User(id: Option[Long], version: Long, name: String, age: Int) extends Base with HasWithId[User] {
  def withId(id: Long): User = this.copy(id = Some(id))
}

def insert[M <: Base with HasWithId[M]](m: M) = {
  m.withId(10)
}
```

Comment: Hi @Ben Reich, I'm using a solution like that for update the version attribute, but your solution seems cleaner using F-bound, I was trying to find a magic to prevent boilerplate, but it boilerplate is acceptable. Thanks